# While loop in a while does loop forever PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, phpmyadmin

I'm making a while loop so the code reads out how much goals there are scored.
This works with a counter as you can see `$scorecounter = 1;` and `$scorecounter++;`.
It also adds if 1 one goal is scored, one goal to the player.
And when there is scored 6 times it does the while loop 6 times.

Everything works but the only thing that doesn't work is that te page keeps loading. Like it's doing the loop forever. The page doesn't refresh, it keeps doing the second while loop forever.

I know it has something to do with:

```
while ($scorecounter <= $scorecounter) {
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO goals (PlayerID, GameID, Name, Team, added_on) VALUES ('$IDdpt', '$Gamedpt', '$Namedpt', '$comp', '$date')");
                }
```

But i can't find the fault where it's doing the line forever.

Here is my whole code:

```
<?php
$Gamedpt = $row['ID'];
$IDdpt = $_POST['ID1'];
$Namedpt = $_POST['player1']; 

$scorecounter = 1;

if (stristr($row['Hometeam'],"$club")) {
    $totalgoals = $row['Thuisscore'];
}
if (stristr($row['Awayteam'],"$club")) {
    $totalgoals = $row['Uitscore'];
}
while ($doelpuntcounter <= $totalgoals) {

if ($_POST["score1"] == "$scorecounter") {
    echo $_POST["player1"];
    echo " has $scorecounter times scored";
    mysql_query("UPDATE players SET Goals = Goals+'$scorecounter' WHERE Naam ='".$_POST["player1"]."'");
                    while ($scorecounter <= $scorecounter) {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO goals (PlayerID, GameID, Name, Team, added_on) VALUES ('$IDdpt', '$Gamedpt', '$Namedpt', '$comp', '$date')");
            }

    }
    $scorecounter++;
}
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: `while ($scorecounter <= $scorecounter)`, that will give you an infinite loop because `$scorecounter` will always be equal to itself.

Comment: In what do i need to change it to, so it will be equal to the number of goals are filled in

Comment: In addition to @NaijaProgrammer: Where is `$doelpuntcounter` incremented (the outer loop)???

Comment: From your question, total lack of understanding and clear level of incompetence regarding planning and security - you would benefit from reading [PHP: The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

My advice to you would be work out your problem, plan your solution and then write the code.  Clearly you're a beginner from the above, so you should spend some time researching and learning more about PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted in the comment:

`while ($scorecounter <= $scorecounter)`

that will give you an infinite loop because $scorecounter will always be equal to itself.

You need something like this to stop the infinte loop:

```
$loop_breaker = 0;
while ( ++$loop_breaker <= $scorecounter) {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO goals (PlayerID, GameID, Name, Team, added_on) VALUES ('$IDdpt', '$Gamedpt', '$Namedpt', '$comp', '$date')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two flaws in your code. I have intended the code and added some comments. Please read the warning below as well.

```
while ($doelpuntcounter <= $totalgoals) {
    if ($_POST["score1"] == "$scorecounter") {
        echo $_POST["player1"] . " has $scorecounter times scored.";
        mysql_query("UPDATE players SET Goals = Goals+'$scorecounter' WHERE Naam ='".$_POST["player1"]."'");
        while ($scorecounter <= $scorecounter) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO goals (PlayerID, GameID, Name, Team, added_on) VALUES ('$IDdpt', '$Gamedpt', '$Namedpt', '$comp', '$date')");
            $scorecounter++; // needs to be in this while loop, flaw #1 !
        }

    }
    // additionally, where is your $doelpuntcounter incremented???
    // flaw #2
}
```

Furthermore, you are still using the old `mysql` functions. Instead, try to use the newer `mysqli` functions or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the following line:

`while ($scorecounter <= $scorecounter) { ... }`

You can also view this as checking whether 1 is smaller or equal to 1. This is an equivalent of `while (true) { ... }` and thus will cause an infinite loop. You probably meant the following:

`while ($scorecounter <= $totalgoals) { ... }`